# Classic word or phrase for many in one

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am looking for a word which describes many in one in classic english. If possible please provide modern word ideas as well.

Comment: In what context do you intend to use the word?  What is "classic" English?

Comment: Classical English, intended use is many things at one place for example amazon.com, you can buy many things on one website.

Comment: Are you restricting this to a marketplace?  I still don't know what "Classical" English is.

Comment: @deadrat perhaps it is that variety of English that was spoken in classical antiquity.

Comment: @phoog That's the answer I'm worried I'll get.

Comment: "E pluribus unum" is certainly classical, though I'm not sure it counts as "English".

Comment: @HotLicks As the phrase adorning the United States seal, it's surely good enough for Amazon's strict classical style rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***conglomeration*** works for people, things, stuff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of **objects** a *quantity*
Of **people** a *crowd*

A *plethora* has been discussed here recently.
A *galaxy,* a *multitude,* a *host,* describe an enormous number in one.
(hyperbole)

A *handful*, a *bunch*, are much less formal and describe a smaller number (of objects or people)

This list should open a number of thesaurus lists for you.